# Why is `KUBE_NAMESPACE` not set anymore?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-autodevops

I'm using Gitlab autodevops with a Kubernetes cluster(Gitlab runner with the Kubernetes Executor).

A while ago the deployments used to be in project specific namespaces like `project-5648-nut-qa-9yg86f`, but now they are deployed in `default`.

The namespace is determined with `KUBE_NAMESPACE` which should be automatically set by gitlab accoriding to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/deploy_to_cluster.html#deployment-variables).
I created a simple Job to get the environment variables:

```
env build:
  extends: .auto-deploy
  stage: build
  tags: 
    - nut
  script:
    - env
    - auto-deploy ensure_namespace
  environment:
    name: nut/staging
    url: https://$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG.nut.$KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN
```

But there is no variable called `KUBE_NAMESPACE` in there and `auto-deploy ensure_namespace` uses the `default`namespace

```
$ auto-deploy ensure_namespace
NAME      STATUS   AGE
default   Active   230d
```

Why is `KUBE_NAMESPACE` not set? 
The server with the cluster has been rebooted a few times.
Everytime it reboots a new runner is created, is it possible that this is the cause of the error?
And how can I get a value for `KUBE_NAMESPACE` again?